# How to avoid switch-case in a factory method of child classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Lets say we have a family of classes (cards, for the sake of it), and we need to instantiate them based on some identifier.
A factory method would look like this:

```
public Card GetCard(int cardNumber) 
{
   switch(cardNumber) 
   {
     case 13: return new King();
     case 12: return new Queen();
     case 11: return new Jack();          
   }

   //...
}
```

What I want is to avoid this `switch`. Why? Maybe I want to reuse this comparison in the feature.

What I came up with is something like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, Type> cardTypes = 
 { 
   {13, typeof(King)},
   {12, typeof(Queen)},
   {11, typeof(Jack)}
 };

 public Card GetCard(int cardNumber) 
 {        
    var cardType = cardTypes[cardNumber];
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(cardType);
    return (Card)instance;
 }
```

However, this solution uses reflection which is expensive, and is also problematic when you have more than one "identifier" (for example 1 and 14 both give `Ace` - should I add 2 keys to the dictionary?).

What's the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: I personally think if the collection of types is Fixed AND Clearly-known AND Short (in human-sense) a Factory pattern adds to much overhaul, your first solution could be fine enough. If it needs to be extensible OR read-for-unknown-future-types OR Huge, a factory could do. But that is most debatable ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Instead of storing the *type* in the dictionary, you could store a `Func<Card>`:

```
private Dictionary<int, Func<Card>> cardFactories = 
{
    { 13, () => new King() },
    // etc
}

public Card GetCard(int cardNumber) 
{        
    var factory = cardFactories[cardNumber];
    return factory();
}
```

In the case of cards, I'd probably make them immutable to start with and just populate the dictionary with the cards themselves, but that's a different matter :)

Comment: @Caspar: Yes, you could certainly use constants instead. That's not really the point of the question though, which is what I was trying to address...

Comment: this is a great solution, thanks! A. What about the Ace problem? would you duplicate the Ace Func twice for 1 and 14? B. What if each card needs to get a parameter, say, a `Suit` (color) object? Would you create a delegate of `Card delg(Suit)` and then use `(suit) => new King(suit)` in the dictionary?

Comment: @yellowblood: It would depend on the *real* situation, which presuambly *isn't* for cards. Why would you have two identifiers for the same value? Can you canonicalize first, for example?

Comment: @Caspar: I think magic numbers would make sense in this thing; the entire cardFactories is the constant, really. (of course, I'd make it `static reaonly`)