# How to implement elegant animal farm?

Tags: c#, generics, factory

Is there an elegant way (using generics and/or Activator and/or any other nice trick) to implement object factory other than big switch for following scenario?

```
enum AnimalKind
{
    Bear,
    Fox,
    Ant,
}

abstract class Animal
{
    abstract AnimalKind Kind {get;}
    ...
    static Animal Create(AnimalKind kind) // Factory method, convert kind to animal
    {
        switch (kind)
        {
            case AnimalKind.Bear: return new Bear();
            ...
            // Update this part anytime the new AnimalKind is added
        }
    }
}

class Bear : Animal
{
    override AnimalKind Kind {get {return AnimalKind.Bear;}}
    ...
}
...
```

Unfortunately the **animal kind is the requirement** and the desired purpose is following transformation: `List<AnimalKind> => List<Animal>`. Otherwise something like `T Create<T>() where T:Animal` would be possible. As the new animals occur in the system, the less updates in the code the better (ideal case is the enum and the animal class itself, nothing in the factory method).

**Edit:**
Based on the comments below, the best answer is [here](http://techtaunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/factory-pattern-with-reflection-c/)!

**Edit 2:**

- As I'm mot able to answer question closed as duplicate,
- As the referenced answer does not satisfy me,
- As there is no problem with probably poor performance due to the reflection on the animal farm,
- Also for the people who wanted the copy/paste "working examples"

I'm posting my solution here. Feel free to rearrange and/or improve and/or simplify it:

**`Animal.cs:`**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionFactory
{
    public enum AnimalKind
    {
        None,
        Bear,
        Fox, 
        Ant,
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public const AnimalKind StaticKind = AnimalKind.None;
        public abstract AnimalKind Kind {get;}

        // That is the "trick" I was looking for: kind => Animal, no further changes
        public static Animal Create(AnimalKind kind)
        {
            var asm  = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var type = asm.GetTypes()
                          .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal)))
                          .FirstOrDefault(t => (AnimalKind)(t.GetField("StaticKind").GetValue(null)) == kind);

            // FIXME: Might want to check for unwanted type values (like null)

            return (Animal)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }

    public class Bear : Animal
    {
        public new const AnimalKind StaticKind = AnimalKind.Bear;
        public override AnimalKind Kind {get{return StaticKind;}}
        // ...
   }

    public class Fox : Animal
    {
        public new const AnimalKind StaticKind = AnimalKind.Fox;
        public override AnimalKind Kind {get{return StaticKind;}}
        // ...
    }

    public class Ant : Animal
    {
        public new const AnimalKind StaticKind = AnimalKind.Ant;
        public override AnimalKind Kind {get{return StaticKind;}}
        // ...
    }
}
```

**`Program.cs:`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ReflectionFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var shoppingList = new List<AnimalKind>
            {
                AnimalKind.Bear,
                AnimalKind.Bear,
                AnimalKind.Fox,
                AnimalKind.Ant,
                AnimalKind.Ant,
                AnimalKind.Ant,
            };

            var animalFarm = shoppingList.Select(Animal.Create);

            foreach (var animal in animalFarm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(animal.Kind);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have elected for composition over inheritance in this scenario? Inheritance seems like a nicer option here.. it would also remove the need for your factory.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5847468/142904

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Sorry the Bear should of course inherit from Animal (I wrote this here, not copied from anywhere). I'll edit it.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example. If you put this in a console app, it isn't working. It should be nice having an example that actually is working.

Comment: @Kristian Damian Nice, thanks, but the dictionary actually is the switch (in different form).

Comment: Try to make a console app that's functioning and describe your problem, that would make things easier...

Comment: If they all inherit from `Animal`.. what is the point of the `enum` when you could just write: `var bear = Animal.Create(new Bear());` instead of: `var bear = Animal.Create(AnimalKind.Bear);`. But then.. what's the point of the static method anyway then... ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your point. You get a list of IDs and you deliver list of animals. `Animal.Create` should be generic factory method generating animals depending on the animal kind and in ideal case should be constant even if you modify the set of existing animal kinds.

Comment: @Complexity Yes, this is just a general example used for the problem illustration, not a snippet from big working program.

Comment: @sharpener you can use reflection http://techtaunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/factory-pattern-with-reflection-c/

Comment: @Kristian Damian That's the point! Thanks.